# Multiple Maven Projects, Single JaCoCo Site?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, jacoco

I am working for a company that is using multiple Maven projects/modules to create what will eventually become one product. To help me explain, imagine a file structure similar to below:

```
- Parent Directory
     - Project_1
           - /src/
           - /target/
           - POM.xml
     - Project_2
           - /src/
           - /target/
           - POM.xml
```

Along the way we are using JUnit to unit test our code, and it is an important contractual requirement that we achieve above a certain percentage threshold of code coverage with our tests.

We are using **JaCoCo** to generate coverage reports in the form of a HTML website. JaCoCo itself is proving to be invaluable but one major problem we have is that this creates a single site under the `/target/site/jacoco/` directory.

I have done some investigating myself and found that, unless I am mistaken, JaCoCo by default does not support the ability to converge multiple Maven projects into a single JaCoCo report.

So my question is, can anybody suggest an alternative solution - something that will allow us to converge multiple reports onto a single web server?

One option we have is to move all sites into individual folders on a web server and then have an index page linking them together, but it's "clumsy" at best. For example:

```
- Web Server
     - index.html
     - Project_1
           - (Generated report files)
     - Project_2
           - (Generated report files)
```

Any better suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use Ant Task ( http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html ) for generation of report that gives more flexibility than Maven Plugin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JaCoCo does not provide a simple way to do this as of today. However, they do specify three alternatives that are described here: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule

Their most suitable approach involves creating a separate reporter module that contains dependencies on all the other modules (*in the github article referred to as Strategy: Module with Dependencies*).

The reporter module uses the *jacoco:report-aggregate* (http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) maven goal to fetch all the individual reports and binds them together into one.

An example project:

https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Maven/Chapter_06_-_Jacoco_report_aggregation.jsp

Answer (score 1):

There are many different approaches you can go with.

First of all you might want to consider something like Sonar, so that you'll compile all your modules and will run a Sonar that will inspect the coverage among other things. Sonar will take the results and upload to sonar server (with the database and everything) so that you'll be able to see in UI what went wrong

Another approach is just rolling your own Maven plugin (assuming you're using Maven). The reports generated by jacoco is also an XML report if I'm not mistaken. So it can be parsed pretty easily. So, one could write a Maven plugin that would identify all the reports like this, parse them and provide some unified view.

Yet another approach is to cause the whole build failure when the coverage doesn't reach some threshold. I know, it doesn't answer your question directly, but if you do it like this, you'll kind of guarantee the minimum level of coverage (that can be increased from time to time at the level of project).